# Host is unresolved: api.twitter.com:80

Tags: android, twitter

I am implementing twitter for android.  When i am requesting for Request Token.  It throws me this error:

04-27 11:25:01.163: DEBUG/ERROR=(3467): Host is unresolved: api.twitter.com:80

Before it was working fine.  Suddenly it started giving this error.

Thanks in advance,  aby

Comment: what version of android are you using? which phone have you tried? and have you tried to type the same address from browser to see that the service is reachable or not?

Comment: I am running on emulator on 2.2 version.  I didnt got the Oauth URL from the Twitter that why i was not able to test it on the browser..

Comment: @Aby, what Twitter SDK are you using, if any?

Comment: @Aby, did you ever get this figured out?

Comment: @arcain: i think the error was with twitter.

Answer (score 0):

That sounds like a DNS lookup error.  If you have a network tool suite installed that allows nameserver lookups ([GTech Net Tools](https://market.android.com/details?id=com.glasertech.android.nettools&feature=search_result) is one of these, and it's free) try entering **api.twitter.com** to see if your emulator can resolve the IP address.

One other thing to note is that you should be using **HTTPS** to call the OAuth resources at Twitter. From the **:80** on your request, you can tell that whatever called [oauth/request_token](http://dev.twitter.com/doc/post/oauth/request_token) used plain old **HTTP**. All network communication involved in negotiating your OAuth tokens should be secured.

Answer (score 0):

I understand that we can use HTTP as well(If your system lacks a security cert). You can tell the library to use HTTP call by adding the following line before the initializing the Twitter connection object.

System.setProperty("twitter4j.http.useSSL","false");

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and after many tries it seems that the problem was in the emulator.. **when trying the program on 1.5 it worked. However, it didn't work on 2.1**. I opened the native emulator browser on 2.1 and it failed to load the google page (probably the emulator got an internet connection problem)